# Does Animal Friendship work on a Wild Shaped druid?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wild-shape

Can somebody cast animal friendship on a druid who has used wild shape and have it affect them like it would an ordinary Beast?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The short answer is yes, if your druid has less than 4 intelligence.

The spell lists one requirement for targeting and an additional requirement I'll talk about.

PHB, page 212, Animal Friendship:

> Choose a beast that you can see within range,
>   It must see and hear you. If the beast's Intelligence is 4 or higher, the spell fails.

For the first requirement — creature type — Druids' Wild shape does cause the player's creature type to change to beast.

PHB, page 67:

> ... Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast, but you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, W isdom , and Charisma scores. You also retain all of your skill and saving throw proficiencies, in addition to gaining those of the creature...

This makes clear that your natural statistics are replaced by the beasts statistics including creature type.

For the additional requirement, the Druid maintains it's normal humanoid Intelligence.  What this means is if your druid has at least 4 intelligence and is in wild shape the spell WILL fail, but it still works as if you'd cast the spell on a beast with at least 4 intelligence as normal.

Comment: OK, so if the druid has Intelligence less than four, they presumably have had there Intelligence reduced, maybe with Feeblemind. So then what happens when they have had Animal Friendship successfully cast on them, and then later Feeblemind is countered and their intelligence increases to 10+.

Comment: @gmatht this is one of those exceptional circumstances where we'd expect the DM to make a judgment call about what is most reasonable to the story. Rules-as-written, you would almost certainly stay charmed for the entire duration. This is not too onerous as it just means that you cannot initiate combat with them and they get advantage on social interaction checks; you aren't *enslaved* to them or anything. But there would be a good option for DM overrulings if, say, they are brutalizing your companions while you are charmed and you previously couldn't understand that.

Answer (score 11):

Only if the druid in question has an intelligence score of 3 or less.  The Animal Friendship spell description states that the spell fails if the beast has a 4 or greater intelligence, and the Wild Shape ability states that the wild shaped druid retains his own intelligence (and wisdom and charisma) score.